# iframe ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a requirement to load the templates in the iframe, so i have written this code

```
<div class="col m8 l8 s12 margin-top-30" id="hue-demo-bg-div">
     <iframe id="myiframe" src="/themes/{{$themeid}}.html" width="560" height="550" style="border-width: 0; position:fixed;"></iframe>
</div>
```

I am loading my templates html file dynamically, in that html file i have written some script but it gives me error as

> ReferenceError: $ is not defined

But i loaded the jquery.min.js in the file in which iframe div is written. But it's not loading the js from that page. As i load the js in the theme page it will not give error. But i have to load the js in each theme. Any solution to doesn't load the js in the theme file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alter the `src` in script block:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var sourceTxt = "/themes/" + $('#themeid').html();
        $("#myiframe").attr("src", sourceTxt);
    });
</script>
```

And put in the bottom of page, to alter the `src` after page loads.